# Inconsistent Behavior of Python Function Across Different Input Cases

Tags: python

Recently I have been honing my Python skills by making beginner friendly cyber security-oriented projects in Python. I am trying to build a subdomain finder. It is working as intended but the function that i wrote to handle errors fails to be executed for some inputs and executed successfully for others. My entire code is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests 
import sys

# A function to print out errors.
def throw_error(error_num, further_info=None): 

    # TODO: Sentitize the value of further_info.

    error_message = {
        1: "[\033[35mError:\033[0m] usage: ./script.py [SUBDOMAINS_LIST_PATH] [TARGET_URL]",
        2: f"[\033[35mError:\033[0m] no such file: {further_info}",
        3: "[\033[35mError:\033[0m] you need to type in the full URL like: http(s)://example.com",
        4: f"[\033[35mError:\033[0m] problem establishing a network connection to {further_info}."
    }

    return error_message[error_num]

# A function to find a substring of a given string and insert some string after it.
def insert_after(source, target, insert_string):
    index = source.find(target)
    if index != -1:
        new_string = source[:index + len(target)] + insert_string + '.' + source[index + len(target):]
        return new_string
    else:
        throw_error(3)
        sys.exit(1)

if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    throw_error(1)
    sys.exit(1)

# Path to the subdomains list.
list_path = sys.argv[1]

try:
    with open(list_path, "r") as file:
        # The subdomains list content.
        subdomain_list = file.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    throw_error(2, list_path)
    sys.exit(1)

# All the subdomains in the file.
subdomins = subdomain_list.splitlines()

# Iterete through all the subdomains.
for subdomain in subdomins:
    # Construct a full url.
    full_url = insert_after(sys.argv[2], "://", subdomain)

    try:
        # Sending get request and saving the response as response object.
        response = requests.get(full_url)
        status_code = response.status_code
        status_code_message = {
            100: "[\033[34mInformational\033[0m]",
            200: "[\033[32mSuccessful\033[0m]",
            300: "[\033[33mRedirection\033[0m]",
            400: "[\033[30mClient Error\033[0m]",
            500: "[\033[31mServer Error\033[0m]",
            000: "[\033[31mInvalid Status Code\033[0m]",
        }

        if 100 <= status_code < 200:
            print(f"{status_code_message[100]} {status_code : >8} {full_url :>5}")
        elif 200 <= status_code < 300:
            print(f"{status_code_message[200]} {status_code : >8} {full_url :>5}")
        elif 300 <= status_code < 400:
            print(f"{status_code_message[300]} {status_code : >8} {full_url :>5}")
        elif 400 <= status_code < 500:
            print(f"{status_code_message[400]} {status_code : >6} {full_url :>5}")
        elif 500 <= status_code < 600:
            print(f"{status_code_message[500]} {status_code : >8} {full_url :>5} \033[31m TCP connection to the web server could not be established. It could get blocked which is an indicator of a firewall in place.\033[0m")
        else:
            print(f"{status_code_message[600]} {status_code : >8} {full_url :>5}")
        
    except requests.ConnectionError as error:
        print(f"{throw_error(4, full_url)}")

    # TODO Handle other exceptions.
```

**The Expected Behavior:**

My error-handling function should consistently catch and handle errors, regardless of the input provided. I've reviewed the logic multiple times and can't pinpoint the issue causing this inconsistency.

**Different Scenarios:**

**Case1:** If I run the script without providing the full three arguments which are the script name, the domain, and the subdomain list to be bruteforced, the `throw error` function must be triggered and print out the message `usage: ./script.py [SUBDOMAINS_LIST_PATH] [TARGET_URL]`. But it does not print that out.

**Case2:** If the path of the subdomain list file does not exit, the `throw error` function must be triggered and print out the message `[\033[35mError:\033[0m] no such file: {further_info}`. But it does not print that out.

**Case3:** If the user enter a URL without providing it completely like not typing the `https://` part, the `throw error` function must be triggered and print out the message `[\033[35mError:\033[0m] you need to type in the full URL like: http(s)://example.com`. But it does not print that out.

**Case4:** If the subdomain being bruteforced does not exist, a connection issue will be raised and the `throw error` function must be triggered and print out the message `[\033[35mError:\033[0m] problem establishing a network connection to {further_info}.`, which it does print it out as intended. And here is a screen shot of the output of the case 4:

[image]

**Attempts and Troubleshooting:**
I've attempted to debug this by printing out intermediate values and checking variable states during execution. Despite my efforts, I can't seem to identify the root cause.

**Note:**
I run this script on both my Windows and on my Kali box and had the same results on both of them.

I am sure the resolution of this issue is so trivial but I am not able to catch it.

Comment: Why are you expecting `throw_error` to print the associated error message? There aren't any `print` statements in the function def

Comment: OMG, I have spent hours trying to figure out what I was missing. Thank you so much for pointing that out! I can't believe I missed such a simple detail. Your observation helped me identify the issue, and now my code is working as intended. I really appreciate your assistance!